# System.Collections.Concurrent missing classes

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, .net-assembly, concurrent-collections

I've got the final release Visual Studio 2013 working on an MVC4 project.  .NET 4.5 is the target platform.  When I reference the `System` assembly all I see is `BlockingCollection<T>` and `ConcurentBag<T>` in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.  According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) there a bunch more classes that should be there.  I'm looking for the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` here in particular.

Full path to the assembly:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll`

Update: When I try to reference `mscorlib.dll` I get the error `A reference to 'mscorlib' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this was really stupid mistakes I was making.  The classes were there all along in mscorlib assembly. mscorlib was already referenced, as could be seen in the Object Browser, it just wasn't showing up in Solution Explorer so I didn't spot it right away.  I also didn't complete the data type with `<TKey, TValue>`.  So yeah, it's all there.